# Overriding UIPanGestureRecognizer for UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uipangesturerecognizer

Having some issues getting this to override its superclass - keep getting the error "method does not override any method from its superclass". The collection view and the pan is all set-up, I just want to disable sideways panning (if that's a word).

I'm sticking this right at the bottom of my class:

```
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    if let panGestureRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIPanGestureRecognizer {
        let translation = panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(collectionView!)
        if fabs(translation.y) > fabs(translation.x) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```

Any ideas? I'll post my jazzy collectionview and it's panning-abilities as a rewards for those that contribute.

Comment: I just double checked, it works on my end. Check for spelling mistakes? It looks right in this writeup though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override that method because it's not part of your superclass (UICollectionView). You need to adopt the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol in your class and remove the `override`.

Assuming you've created a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, either in storyboard or programatically, you need to set the delegate of that `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to `self` whenever your view loads.

Also, don't forget to add the panRecognizer to your collection view.

```
panGesture.delegate = self
collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
```

Comment: I had done all of those things you suggested, except removing the 'override'. I feared it wouldn't call it without it, but you're right Mr J...you've fixed my problem. Thanks very much.